# IPython.parallel and distribution of the interpreters on the CPU

Tags: distribution, ipython

I used the following code snippet to test the performance of the IPython.parallel module:

```
dview = c[:]    #use all engines

counter = time.time()
result = dview.map_sync(fib, range(4000))    #fib return the nth Fibonacci number
counter = time.time() - counter
```

I used up to 30 'engines' for this test, which I started over the IPython notebook. Suprisingly the performance scales (non-linear) up with the amount of engines (which are actually full IPython interpreters) even when I move over the limit of my CPU-cores (I have 4 cores). I always thought one engines will be associated to one core and using more engines as cores will just lead to an overhead. What is really happening here? In which way are the engines distributed on the cores?

EDIT: The solution is the comment from Matt plus http://nbviewer.ipython.org/5500077

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In which way are the engines distributed on the cores?

There is nothing specific we do in IPython about that. This is totally handled by the OS and its scheduler.

Still I pretty surprised the time to make the calculation decrease with the number of engine if you are using a direct view and not a load balanced one.

Comment: The performance gets absolutely horrible using the load balanced view. Maybe you have a clue why. And just to get this right: The load balanced view distributes the workload to the engines (hopefully equal) while the OS will distribute the engines to the cores?

Comment: Don't quite remember how the load balanced view split things with map, I'm not using it a lot. My guess is direct split range in 4 chunks (0-1000,1001-2000...) send them make the calculation, and return, wherease loadbalanced will actually send the next calculation as soon as one engine is free. Hence 4000 send, so you will have more overhead in your case. The exact detail depends also on fib implementation. Actually fib is not a good candidate here as all engines will have to at least calculate all back to fib(1) so lots of overlaps.

Comment: Yes, but I did not aim for efficiency regarding the function ;). Just to complete this thread: I mixed the list above up in a way that every terminal would get the same workload. I also fixed every terminal to exactly one core. And what I get with my four cores is nearly 1/4 of the time when you would use just one core. So its working fine. Also your guess with the chunks is correct. I could see this by looking at the cpus: The first core gets the easy part and is proceeding fast while the 4th core gets the hard one and needs some time. Thanks again for your help!